# I have hidden and unreachable workspaces - how do I cancel them?

Tags: unity, pdf, workspaces

I have double workspaces, whether I enable them or not. If *not* enabled, some pdf's open in an unreachable hidden workspace [I know it's there because I can see the Document Viewer open in the launcher]. If I enable workspaces(4 normally), I see the 'double' ones when I go from e.g. no.1 to no.2 using ctrl+alt+arrow, but they're not listed in the launcher, so they remain unreachable. However, when I open some pdf's -not all of them- they open in a hidden workplace and I cannot reach it. Could anybody help? I wouldn't bother if all documents would open in a normal workspace, but as it is I don't manage to get to some of them...

Comment: Any chance you have a second monitor attached, switched of  but *not* disabled in Monitors?

Comment: no 2nd monitor, but thanks to you I looked for monitors in displays and found it was on. So thanks a lot you for your help :-) Problem solved!

Comment: Perfect! I think you could post it as an answer. It could be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

So this is how I found the solution (thanks to Jacob Vlijm):

1. open Dash and type "Display", or go to System Settings and from there click "Displays".
2. Check if "Mirror displays" is ticked (1st line) and/or if it is On or Off (2nd line). Play around with those two until you get to the desired situation. Note that the On/Off button works only when the Mirror Display (1st line) is un-ticked. Good luck!